# Web Based Stack Dump Tool for ASP.NET Using Mdbg?

Tags: asp.net, multithreading, debugging, callstack, mdbg

There is a great [presentation](http://www.infoq.com/presentations/MySpace-Dan-Farino) by Dan Farino, Chief Systems Architect at **MySpace.com**, showcasing a web-based stack dump tool that catalogues all threads running in a given process (what they're doing, how long they've been executing, etc.)

Their techniques are also summarized on [highscalability.com](http://highscalability.com/myspace-architecture):

- **PerfCollector**.
  Centralized 
  collection of performance data via
  UDP. More reliable than Windows and
  allows any client to connect and see
  stats.
- **Web Based Stack Dump Tool.**
  Can right-click on a problem server
  and get stack dump of the .Net
  managed threads. Used to have to RDC
  into system and attach a debugger and
  1/2 later get an answer. Slow,
  nonscalable, and tedious. Not just a
  stack dump, gives a lot of context
  about what the thread is doing.
  Troubleshooting is easier because you
  can see 90 threads are blocked on a
  database so the database may be down.
- **Web Base Heap Dump Tool.**
  Dumps all
  memory allocations. Very useful for
  developers. Save hours of doing it by
  hand.  •  Profiler. Traces a request
  from start to finish and produces a
  report. See URL, methods, status,
  everything that will help you
  identify a slow request. Looks at
  lock contentions, are a lot of
  exceptions being thrown, anything
  that might be interesting. Very light
  weight. It's running on one box in
  every VIP (group of 100 servers) in
  production. Samples 1 thread every 10
  seconds. Always tracing in
  background.

**The question is: what tools are required to build a web-based stack dump tool for ASP.NET?** For convenience, let's assume that an *.aspx hosted in the target AppDomain, able to output all managed call stacks in that process, is sufficient.

There are a few posts that cover the use of **Mdbg** (debugger for managed code written entirely in C#/IL that started shipping with CLR 2 SDK) and the **mdbgcore** assembly typically found in C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\SDK\v2.0\Bin:

- http://dotnetdebug.net/2005/11/09/exceptiondbg-v01-debug-your-exceptions/
- http://blogs.msdn.com/jmstall/archive/tags/MDbg/default.aspx
- http://blogs.msdn.com/vijaysk/archive/2009/11/04/asp-net-debugger-extension-for-iis-7.aspx

Would a solution simply reference this assembly to produce the desired output? What impact would a "list all managed call-stacks" operation have on the running process that's servicing production traffic?

Answer (score 3):

I believe the profiling API of .Net are the way to go.

Look at the [SlimTune](http://code.google.com/p/slimtune/) project on Google Code to have a live sample, with sources, that you can check how to adapt and improve to work in a Asp.NET scenario.

Regards
Massimo

Answer (score 2):

With the profiling API of .Net you have to stop the server and it takes a lot CPU (but it gives you full control over all called methods).

I think the most “light way” solution is to doing this with MDbg, I put together a very small but useful little app called [StackDump](http://epiwiki.se/tools/stackdump) that does the following:
1) The debugger stops the application and generates a list of all CLR stacks running for the process. 
2) The application is started again. 
This operation is a quick operation and can (maybe) be executed on a running production server with unchanged production code.

It just 80 lines of .Net code to manage this.  I have published the [source code](http://stackdump.codeplex.com/) on Codeplex.